# TensorFlow gather_nd indexing semantics

Tags: tensorflow

Given the following `gather_nd` example

```
import tensorflow as tf

B = 8
H = 5
W = 5
C = 3

X = tf.zeros([B, H, W, C])

# Indices for the first three diagonal elements.
idx_y = [0, 1, 2]
idx_x = [0, 1, 2]
idx = tf.stack([idx_y, idx_x], axis=-1)

Y = tf.gather_nd(X, idx, batch_dims=1)
```

Where the index tensor `idx` evaluates to

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [1 1]
 [2 2]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

I expected the `gather_nd` operation to gather the elements `X[:, 0, 0, :]`, `X[:, 1, 1, :]` and `X[:, 2, 2, :]` and yield a tensor of shape `[B, 3, 1, C]` (or some permutation thereof).

However, there is an inconsistency between the number of elements and the requested shape in a `Reshape` op called as part of `gather_nd` execution, as evident by the following error snippet

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 6 values, but the requested shape has 16 [Op:Reshape]
```

My (obviously incorrect) understanding is that the when specifying the first dimension to be a batch dimension (via `batch_dims=1`), the index tensor `idx` does not need to specify batch indices. So in my example, disregarding batch, I expected `idx` to index into the spatial dimensions (`y < H` and `x < W`) following the batch dimension, where each `y, x` index pair corresponds to a `(1, C)` slice of `X`. [Documentation for tf.gather_nd on batched tensors.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd#batches)

***What have I misunderstood about the semantics of my index tensor `idx` and the interplay between it and the `batch_dims` kwarg of `gather_nd` in the given example?***

Comment: Almost there. Try: `tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(XX, tf.concat([tf.repeat(tf.tile(tf.range(B), multiples=[tf.shape(idx)[0]]), repeats=C)[..., None], tf.repeat(idx, repeats=B*C, axis=0), tf.tile(tf.range(C), multiples=[tf.shape(idx)[0]*B])[..., None]], axis=-1), batch_dims=0), (B, 1, tf.shape(idx)[0], C))`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. However, what I am specifically interested in with this question is the interplay between indexing where the batch indices are not included in the index tensor, i.e. `batch_dims=1` in this case. It appears that your solution does include batch indices in the `idx` tensor.

Comment: Ah ok then you have to explicitly Index `C`